# PSQL not prompting for password in PowerShell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, authentication, password-protection

This PSQL statement in PowerShell:

```
.\psql --% -h localhost -p 5000 -U postgres -d mydatabase -c `
(SELECT * ...... do something);
```

Works - and does not prompt for a password.

```
.\psql.exe --help
```

States the -w switch is required for no password.

Why does this command work without a password? The database has a password.

The command does not work in the PSQL interactive shell without password authentication, only in PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-w` is not required for "no password" reread what it says, from my `man psql`

> `-w` `--no-password` Never issue a password prompt. **If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail.** This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password. Note that this option will remain set for the entire session, and so it affects uses of the meta-command \connect as well as the initial connection attempt.

`-w` is meant for when you're running psql scripts and input for a password is not possible, like in a headless session.

> Why does this command work without a password? The database has a password.

Even if the database *has* a password, if your `pg_hba.conf` file has trust no password will be required. To debug this further we need to see your `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: This line in pg_hba.conf under IPv4 local connections: host all all x.x.x.x password is presumably the cause. Since database is set to 'all'. Thanks for your help.